# Android MediaPlayer Does not Play Remote URL

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I have example MediaPlayer that plays the example URL but does not play any other remote URL I tried including from YouTube.
What am I missing?

It just return "Can't Play This Video"

```
   package com.ebookfrenzy.videoplayer;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.VideoView;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.util.Log;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;

public class VideoPlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String TAG = "VideoPlayer";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_player);

        final VideoView videoView =
                (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);

        videoView.setVideoPath(
                "https://youtu.be/1iGy1Rp93o4");
     //           "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4");
     //           "http://www.ebookfrenzy.com/android_book/movie.mp4");

        MediaController mediaController = new
                MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new
                MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener()  {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Duration = " +
                                videoView.getDuration());
                    }
                });

        videoView.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can access youtube video via it url using a videoView as youtube use it own streaming structure so if need to play youtube video you have to use there api witch is well documented and easy to integrate please considere visit the link below
https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/